# Open and then kill a browser window in a nodejs script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

So I've been trying to write a script that needs to open a browser window to do google oauth. Now the problem is I can use [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) to open the browser window, but I can't find a way to close it after the auth happens. It just stays there.

Comment: spawn returns - use it to kill

Comment: That package uses spawn, and it says it returns the process.  So you should be able to call kill on this.  The problem you might have is how do you know when the Auth is done.  Have you looked at puppeteer as that's good for automating Chrome browser.

Comment: I tried calling kill on it, via it's pid. Nothing happens.

Comment: @Estradiaz the pid returned seems to be useless in Linux. You cannot kill it on Linux either using childProcess.kill('SIGKILL') or process.kill(-childProcess.id) or process.kill(childProcess.id). It simply does not work. It throws: Error: kill ESRCH

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure this what your asking, but you can do this by sending the response to the page like code shown below.

```
router.get('/yourpage',(req, res) => {
  res.send("<script>window.close();</script > ")})
```

so basically when your page gets opened this will send the close script from the server-side to the client by instructing close the window.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm not really running a proper server using express or fastify.